# Error connecting to SQL Server using ODBC on R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I have successfully created and tested an ODBC Data Source Object for SQL Server on my windows, however when I run the following in RStudio to connect the db:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "ReadUser")
```

I get the following error:
`Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: 28000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.`

[image: ODBC SetUp]

[image: Successful Test]

Would appreciate any assistance in completing the setup of SQL Server on R.

Comment: Your title says SHOUTS (please do not SHOUT at us) MySQL, but your images of errors ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) says SQL Server; which is it..?

Comment: Also, if you *are* trying to connect to a SQL Server instance, *why* are you using such an old version of the ODBC driver? The latest release is version 18. Version 10 is completely out of date.

Comment: Hey @ThomA thanks - 
I meant SQL Server, see, I am trying this for the first time, tutorials on this are from 2 years ago. 

If the old version works? What do you recommend?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you attempting to connect to? ODBC Driver 10 for SQL Server is so old that is isn't even listed on the [SQL version compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility) any more. You need to choose an ODBC Driver version that's appropriate to your SQL Server version. ODBC Driver 10 was released with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is this screenshot that successfully tests connection? Bitness of compatibility of ODBC DSN and R.exe (32-bit vs 64-bit) can be an issue. Check Odcbcad32.exe of either bitness. Be sure to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) the many online sources for this information.

Comment: @Parfait - The "TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!" message from the "Test Data Source…" button in odbcad32.exe can be misleading because it doesn't seem to do a "normal" ODBC connection. If we click that button when ODBC tracing is enabled, nothing shows up in SQL.LOG.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson how did you work around this?